# Switch case to break an outer loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement, break

This isn't a specific problem that I actually am trying to implement, but it ocurred to me that I do not know how to do this, so I will give a simple example to illustrate:

Suppose we have a `while` loop containing a `switch` statement, for instance:

```
while(some_cond){
    switch(some_var){
        case 1:
            foo();
            break;
        case 2:
            bar();
            break;
    }
}
```

what would we do if we wanted to `break` out of the while loop in `case 1`, say?

We can't do `break; break;`, since the second will never happen.

We also can't do `break` *un*conditionally in the `while` loop, since this would happen in any `case`.

Do we have no choice but to `if (some_var == 1) break;` in the `while` loop, or else append `&& !flag)` to the `while` condition, and set `flag = 1`?

Comment: `goto` will work, though not pretty.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry @Takendarkk, C++, added.

Comment: @herohuyongtao ah, didn't find that, thanks!

Comment: "What would we do if we wanted to break out of the loop in case 1?" Redesign the code cleanly.

Comment: @jameskanze a) that's what I'm asking a suggestion for; b) I was hoping for input on how to do it in any case.

Comment: What is the problem with `if (some_var == 1) break;`?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay There's no problem in this case, but I'm not implementing this code. I was just giving a basic example, I wanted a general solution like the `goto` and `continue` provided.

Comment: Using `if (some_var == 1) break;` is way better than using `goto` though.

Comment: Okay, it seems like the consensus from this Q, and @herohuyongtao's dupe link, is that we should avoid the situation arising. Which I will do. I should have made it clearer that I haven't run in to this problem - it just occurred to me as something I didn't know how to do, and wanted to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Various options, in approximate order of tastefulness:

- Move the loop into a separate function. Use `return` to stop looping.
- Replace `while(1)` with `while(looping)` and set to false to stop looping. Use `continue` if you need to skip the rest of the current iteration.
- Use `goto` to jump past the end of the loop. [How bad can it be?](http://xkcd.com/292/)
- Surround the loop with a `try` block, and `throw` something to stop looping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `goto` (don't go too wild with `goto` though).

```
while ( ... ) {
   switch( ... ) {
     case ...:
         goto exit_loop;

   }
}
exit_loop: ;
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't even know `goto` existed. Thanks.

Comment: In *a lot* of places you'll be sent to jail, you won't pass *Go* and you won't receive $200 if you use `goto`s.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt As long as I don't go wild with `goto`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have your while use a variable modified within your loop.

```
bool shoulEnterLoop = true;
while(shoulEnterLoop ){
  switch(some_var){
    case 1:
      if ( !foo() )
        shoulEnterLoop = false;
      break;
    case 2:
      bar();
      break;
  }
}
```